# Checkbox value set to 1 upon first checked and not changes on unchecked.

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, yii

The value of checkbox is set to value=1 and if i unchecked it gives same value. I have inspect through firebug. Here is my code.

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
'method'=>'get',)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->label($userModel,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($userModel,'email',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>


    <?php echo $form->label($userModel,'Active License'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::checkBox("status",$license->status=='ACTIVE'); ?>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?> 
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And search function is implemented here

```
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
 $('.search-form form').submit(function(){

$.fn.yiiGridView.update('license-grid', {
    data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Comment: Bear in mind that an unchecked checkbox doesn't actually get posted. There are workarounds for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `uncheckValue`
See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBox-detail

```
<?php 
    echo CHtml::checkBox("status", 
            $license->status=='ACTIVE', 
            array('uncheckValue' => 0)); 
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working but if  i explicitly set the value to 0 then it works. Like
      if (!$('.search-form form').status.checked) {
            $('.search-form form').status.value = 0;
        }